# Pass multiple child states changes back to parent for saving

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have a table which is meant to display guest with check marks indicating if they are attending or not. I am having trouble coming up with a way to pass the state from the child component to the parent while maintaining the identity  of which child it came from.

Each row is a component like below

```
GuestRow = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {      
      attending: this.props.data.attending,      
      plusOneAttending: this.props.data.plusOneAttending
    }
  },

  handleCheckboxChange(field, event) {
    if(field == 'plusOne') {
      this.setState({
        plusOneAttending: event.target.checked
      });
    }
    else if (field == 'guest') {
      this.setState({
        attending: event.target.checked
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("error third option for field");
    }
  },

  plusOneRow() {
    return (
      this.props.data.hasPlusOne ?
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="plusOneAttending"
               defaultChecked={this.state.plusOneAttending}
               onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this, 'plusOne')} /> : <span>Sorry you don't have a plus one</span>
    )
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>{this.props.data.name}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"
                 name="attending"
                 defaultChecked={this.state.attending}
                 onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this, 'guest')} />
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.plusOneRow()}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

These are rendered into the parent table container which is

```
RsvpForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      guests: this.props.data.guests
    }
  },

  saveChanges(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //console.log(test);
  },

  render() {
    var guestRows = this.state.guests.map(function(guest){
      return (
        <GuestRow callBackToParent={this.onChildChange} data={guest} />
      )

    }, this);

    return (
      <div id="rsvp">
        <span>Welcome {this.props.data.invitationName}! Thank you for taking part in our wedding!</span>
        <br />
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Guest</th>
              <th>Are you attending?</th>
              <th>Plus one?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {guestRows}
        </table>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.saveChanges}>Save!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

The `guests` object looks like the following. The example has only one guest, but it can be an array of valid guests each with a unique PID.

```
guests: [
        {
          pid: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
          name: "Joe Somebody",
          attending: true,
          hasPlusOne: true,
          plusOneAttending: false
        }
```

I thought about adding the state of the individual `guest` records to the parent component, but how would it work for when `guests` has greater than 2+ records. Do I dynamically add more state items? Or should I use refs to pull data from the child component. But then how do I identify each one uniquely and make sure I am updating the right records on MongoDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example code sample that you can use. What I've done is rudimentary but also not 100% clean, I'd personally probably do it slightly different. I can also advise you to think about something like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).

Anyway, here my pseudo code. So what I've done is basically have the state in the highest form and let the below component only worry about it's props. This is generally a good pattern, you can easily define behavior based on the props and let the above component (after a state change) feed it the new values.

```
Form = React.createClass({
    onGuestChange(id, guest){
        //set state with new guests etc
    }

    render() {
        var guestRows = this.state.guests.map(function(guest) {
            return (
                <Guestrow onGuestChange={this.handleGuestChange} data={guest}></Guestrow?
            );
        })
        return() {
            <div>{guestRows}</div>
        }
    }
});

GuestRow = React.createClass({
    handleAttendingChange(id, event){
        var guest = this.props.data
        guest.attending = event.target.checked;
        this.props.onGuestChange(id, guest);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='attending' checked={this.props.data.attending} onChange={this.handleAttendingChange.bind(this, this.props.data.id)}></input></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thinking about this issue more, Flux makes a lot of sense. But I like how you are using the binding to pass the `(id, event)` up together to keep the changes assigned properly.

Comment: I'd use the binding with Flux as well, it's a very handy pattern that keeps things a bit more separated.

Answer (score 0):

On your parent, make a function to change the state

```
// parent component
addMoreGuest(guest) {
   var guests = _.clone(this.state('guests'));
   guests.push(guest);

   this.setState({guests: guests});
}
```

and then, pass the `addMoreGuest` as a callback like you did with `onChildChange`

```
<Child callback={this.addMoreGuest} />
```

On the child, make a wrapper for the callback

```
triggerCallback(guest) {
   this.props['callback'](guest);
}
```

By this way, you can send the data from the child to the parent and then, updating the state of the parent. Read more about this in [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else ends up here just like me, just take a look at this medium post. [Passing Data Between React Components](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17).

Be sure to watch this video as well [React JS Tutorial 10: Passing data from child to parent components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnRDdEz1FJc).

The important bit is explained in the code below

`App.js`

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {someStateVariable: ''};
        this.callbackFromParentToChild = this.callbackFromParentToChild.bind(this) // IMPORTANT
    }

    // get some value from the child component
    // this callback belongs to the child's context so we have to bind it to
    // this parent's context using this line in the constructor 
    // this.callbackFromParentToChild = this.callbackFromParentToChild.bind(this)

    callbackFromParentToChild(value_from_child_to_parent) {
        this.setState({someStateVariable: value_from_child_to_parent});     
    }

    renderChildComponent() {
       return country_denominations.map((denomination) => (
            <ChildComponent callback_from_parent_to_child={this.callbackFromParentToChild}/>
        ));
    }
}
```

`Denominator.jsx`

```
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
    computeValueToBePassedToParent() {
        value_from_child_to_parent = '' // perform some computation
        this.props.callback_from_parent_to_child(value_from_child_to_parent); // pass the total back to the parent's callback
    }
}
```